# Mapping multiple datasets using Google Fusion Tables - possible?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I've used ArcGIS for a few years but only recently discovered Google Fusion Tables. 2 very simple questions but not ones I've been able to find any information on online - hoping someone in this community might know:

1. Is it possible to plot more than 1 kml file at a time and have all map properly? (e.g., is it possible to recreate how multiple layers would be
   displayed in ArcGIS)
2. Is it possible to plot different shapefile types at the same time? e.g., plot a polygon, then plot polylines superimposed on top of the polygon? or do Fusion Tables only support 1 kml type?

Trial-and-error attempts at getting both 1 & 2 to work suggest it doesn't work, but I was hoping to get a more concrete and documented "yes" or "no" - or whether there is some formatting trick that can be used?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question per question asked here.